# Problems reading a text file from assets with rare characters (á é à è...)

Tags: android, text-files, inputstream, assets, bytearrayoutputstream

i have a txt file on assets folder with content with rare characters, for example with this content:

> Hola
>
> Holà holá es un vetélélà Holà holá es un vetélélà Holà holá es un
>   vetélélà Holà holá es un vetélélà Holà holá es un vetélélà

And i'm using this code for read the txt file from assets and store it on a string:

```
public static String readTxt(Context context, String fileName){
    try {           
        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open(fileName);         
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();          
        int i= is.read(); 

        while (i != -1){
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = is.read();
        }
        is.close();                     
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return "";
}
```

The text is being readed with the correct format (spaces and line jumps are OK), but the rare characters (á à é è... ) are not being readed correctly. I'm reading this:

> Hola\r\n\r\nHol� hol� es un vet�l�l� Hol� hol� es un vet�l�l� Hol�
>   hol� es un vet�l�l� Hol� hol� es un vet�l�l� Hol� hol� es un vet�l�l�

What i'm doing bad? how can read that text correctly **from ASSETS** ?

Comment: read ByteArrayOutputStream.toString() documentation

Comment: here you have the documentation: Returns the contents of this ByteArrayOutputStream as a string. Any changes made to the receiver after returning will not be reflected in the string returned to the caller.

Comment: good. now read the documentation for the method right above that one.

Comment: i tryed with byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8"); but the result is the same, i don't know what im doing wrong... It's just a txt file from notepad.

Comment: ask yourself what encoding is your file in.

Comment: i tryed also with US-ASCII, (no ansi on the possibilities) and didn't works.

Comment: well, i stored the file in UTF-8 and now the problem is solved!!! THANKS A LOT!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just have to get the string with byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8"); and store the txt file with UTF-8 encoding :)

thanks a lot to njzk2